# Symfony Doctrine QueryException Expected Literal, got 'WHERE'

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, createquery

I have a problem using entityManager->createQuery() in my repository class.

```
public function findAllByDateAndUser( \DateTime $from, \DateTime $to, User $user ) {
    return $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery(
        'SELECT wu, a, ai
         FROM ArpanetCompanyWorkBundle:WorkerUsage wu
         JOIN ArpanetCompanyWorkBundle:AttendanceItem ai WITH ( wu.attendanceItem = ai )
         JOIN ArpanetCompanyWorkBundle:Attendance a WITH ( ai.attendance = a )
         WHERE wu.user = :userP
         AND WHERE a.date >= :fromP
         AND WHERE a.date <= :toP'
    )
    ->setParameter( 'userP', $user )
    ->setParameter( 'fromP', $from )
    ->setParameter( 'toP', $to )
    ->getResult();
}
```

I got an error:

> [2/2] QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 344: Error: Expected Literal, got 'WHERE'

Where is the problem?

I know it can be done by using query builder, but I need to get all entities by one database query because of performance reasons.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: In that case you seem to be using a faulty query syntax. You only need one `WHERE`, not `WHERE ... AND WHERE`. I am also unfamiliar with the `JOIN WITH` syntax, shouldn't that be `JOIN ON`?

Comment: have you tried the `join with` without the parenthesis? Shall you use the querybuilder?

Comment: `AND WHERE` was a problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in using `AND WHERE` instead of only `AND`.